# Calculate the deteminant of the matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ with $\det(A)=13$.

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be the rows of the matrix $A$, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\ldots a_1 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3 \ldots \end{pmatrix}$$
Calculate the determinant of the matrix $$B=\begin{pmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2+a_3 \ldots \\ \ldots a_1+4a_3 \ldots \end{pmatrix}$$ When we add a row multiplied by a scalar to an other row the determinant remains the same. If we multiply a row by a scalar the determinant is multiplied by that scalar.

So we have the following? $$\det (A)=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}\Rightarrow 4\cdot \det (A)=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots 4a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2+a_3 \ldots \\ \ldots 4a_3+a_1 \ldots \end{vmatrix}$$ Therefore the determinant of the matrix $B$ is $\det (B)=4\cdot 13=52$. Is that correct?

Comment: That seems reasonable to me

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! @StephenDonovan

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake, but when I tried with $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 13\end{bmatrix}$$I got $\det(B)=13$.

Comment: So the determinant doesn't change although we have 4 times the last row? @Joe

Comment: I got $$B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 52\\ 0 & 1 & 13\\1 & 0 & 52\end{bmatrix}$$with $\det(B)=13$, but please check if that’s what you get.

Comment: I also get $13$, but why? @Joe

Comment: It wasn’t clear to me how you arrived at your last equality, which is why I checked with an example. I know the determinant is multilinear, so that adding a multiple of a row to a different row doesn’t change the determinant, but it’s not clear to me how you do that in your last step. It seems like you try to perform many of those steps at once, but once you’ve changed a row, you cannot add a multiple of what it used to be to another row, without possibly changing the determinant.

Comment: At matrix $A$ the third row is $a_3$. If we multiply that by $4$ don't we multiply also the determinannt? So $$\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots 4a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=4\cdot \det (A)$$ Then to get the matrix $B$ we just add to each line a multiple line of the other and this doesn;t change the value of the determinant. Or is that wrong? @Joe

Comment: You are definitely correct that adding a multiple of one row to another will not change the determinant, but if you try to do that one step at a time, you won’t get to your final equation (since we see the determinant isn’t 52). I think you did it multiple steps at a time, but then you’re adding a multiple of a row from a PREVIOUS matrix.

Comment: Ahh we get: $$\det (A)=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2+a_3 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2+a_3 \ldots \\ \ldots a_3+(a_1+a_2+4a_3)-(a_2+a_3) \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\ldots a_1+a_2+4a_3 \ldots \\  \ldots a_2+a_3 \ldots \\ \ldots a_1+4a_3 \ldots \end{vmatrix}=\det (B)$$ Thanks a lot for you help!! :-) @Joe

Comment: You’re welcome.